# Curl not handling second request c++ until enter is pressed

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have a simple c++ app where a qr scanner reads a code from the scanner, that is used with curl to process a url, it works great on the first scan but when attempting to scan the second time, curl doesnt process the url. until the enter key is pressed on the keyboard, which is not workable.  Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

```
void sendurl(string s){
   curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
   CURL * myHandle;
   CURLcode result;
   myHandle = curl_easy_init ( ) ;
   curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, s.c_str());
   result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );
   curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );
   content();

}


void content() {
   cout << "Please Enter QR Code";
   string mystr;
   getline (cin,mystr);
   while (mystr != "exit"){
       sendurl(mystr);
}
   }


int main () {
   content();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you really asking why there is a `getline` in youre `content` function?

Comment: I´m asking myself why there are infinite loops and a recursion over two functions that you don´t want in the first place. ... The problem is not Curl, but only your code.

Comment: It needs to be in a loop because I want to be able to continue scanning , after a code is scanned it should be ready to scan another one.  That's all this app does .

Comment: @n4zg What you described would make sense, but your code is something different... In content(), you´re scanning *one* time and then an infinite number of requests are made (or 0, if the input was "exit") with this one input. And sendurl() shouldn´t call content(), this makes absolutely no sense and begs for a stack overflow (error, not this site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted

check the differences between your code and this.

```
void sendurl(string s){
   curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
   CURL * myHandle;
   CURLcode result;
   myHandle = curl_easy_init ( ) ;
   curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, s.c_str());
   result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );
   curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );
}


void content() {
   string mystr;
   while (mystr != "exit"){
     cout << "Please Enter QR Code";
     getline (cin,mystr);
     sendurl(mystr);
  }
}


int main () {
   content();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer I will have to test that in the morning, i didn't have the getline in the loop . I will leave you a comment to let you know how I get on . Thank you 

Comment: @n4zg Did you notice that there are more changes (content and sendurl)...?

Comment: Yes I just noticed it doesn't run the content function from sendurl function. It makes sense. I look forward to testing it in the morning.

Comment: @SHR Just tested the code, still the same outcome, first qr code scans properly and curl processes the request, next scan it reads the code but doesnt process the request until the enter key is manually pressed. any suggestions please.

Comment: @deviantfan thanks for the comment, i noticed it works when you type with the keyboard, the input is from a qr scanner, therefore im guessing the problem must be scanner side not sending the enter key after the initial send as it works properly the first time round.